# How to sort array of objects in my component with Angular 5?

Tags: angular, api

Before I say anything else I'd like to say I'm very new to all of this, so try not to get too technical. Thanks! I have an array with objects. Every object has a date and I'm trying to sort them by this date.

```js
async list_all_shifts(){
  try {
    let response = (await this.shiftService.list_all_shifts().toPromise())

    for (let shiftje of response) {
      this.shiften.push(shiftje);
    }

    this.shiften.sort();

  } catch (err) {

  }
}
```

The problem I have is the part where I try to sort the array doesn't really do anything. The shiften array has a number of objects with a date, beginHour, endHour, etc... In my html component, It just shows the dates in random order, and I'd like them sorted. My HTML component looks like this;

```html
<tr *ngFor="let shift of shiften, index as i;">
  <td>{{shift.datum |  date:'EEE, dd/MM/yyyy'}}</strong></td>
  <td>{{ shift.beginuur }}h</td>
  <td> {{ shift.einduur }}h </td>
  <td>{{shift.helpers.ingeschreven.length}}/{{shift.helpers.max}}</td>
  <td><button class="btn btn-success">Inschrijven {{ shift._id }}</button></td>
  <td><button (click)="verwijderShift(shift, shift._id)">Verwijder</button></td>
</tr>
```

Lastly, my service who gets the data looks like this (i'm using a backend with api);

```js
list_all_shifts(): Observable <any> {
  const header = {
    headers: new HttpHeaders({
      'Content-Type': 'application/json',
      'Authorization': localStorage.getItem('token')
    })
  }

  return this.http.get<any>(`${this.API_URL}/shifts`, header)
}
```

Some of it's in dutch but I hope you get what I'm trying to do here!
Thank you in advance.

Comment: I'd guess it's because Angular doesn't detect changes to arrays by default - what if you sort the array *then* assign it to `shiften`? Or trigger a manual change detection after the sort?

Comment: @jonrsharpe as far as I know angular detect such changes (reordering elements) in arrays

Comment: Maybe I missed it, but where is the condition to sort by date? Or dont you wanto to sort it by date?

PS: Angular should detect such changes!

Comment: @J.Knabenschuh I guess that's part of my question. Since the date was the first element of the Object, I was hoping the sort-function would sort by the first element, being the date. Is there a 'sort by' function? 

What is curious though, is that the sort function doesn't seem to sort by anything, not the date, but not anything else, either.

Comment: How your data from request looks like?

Comment: Ah ok, thats actually easy array.sort just sorts by the complete value so maybe by internal index or address. But you can give the function another function handling your comparation. So something like this should work `this.shiften.sort(function(a,b){return a.datum - b.datum})` see https://developer.mozilla.org/de/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/sort

Comment: @J.Knabenschuh Yes! That was it! Except it had to be a date so instead of a.datum I had to use new Date(a.datum).getTime() and the same for b of course. Thank you so much!

Comment: You are welcome. I create an extra post so that other people searching for the same answer get it without reading all the comments.

Answer (score 0):

do it like this:

```
class Component {
    shifts$: Observable<Shift>;
    constructor(private shiftService: ShiftService) {
    }
    ngOnInit(){
         this.shiftService.list_all_shifts()
             .pipe(
                 map(shiftArray => [...shiftArray].sort()),
                 catchError(err => {
                     // handle the error
                     doSth()
                     // return an empty array so you template logic doesnt fail
                     return of([])
                 })
             )
    }

}
```

In your template, use the async pipe:

```
<tr *ngFor="let shift of shifts$ | async, index as i;">
    ...
</tr>
```

From your messy code I can tell, that you aren't using a good IDE. Consider using IntelliJ or VScode and pay attention to your code. Keep it clean and understandable.

Answer (score 0):

To people searching for the same answer. As in the comments written, to get an by date sorted array you have to use the sort-function´s first optional argument "compareFunction". See https://developer.mozilla.org/de/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/sort

```
async list_all_shifts(){
try {
  let response = (await this.shiftService.list_all_shifts().toPromise())

  for (let shiftje of response) {
    this.shiften.push(shiftje);
  }

  this.shiften.sort(function(a, b) {
    return new Date(a.datum).getTime() - new Date(b.datum).getTime();
  });

} catch(err) {}
```